# How to display a Bar Chart in DataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts, datatable

What im try to do is to render bar chart in datatable. I'm using Highchart and DataTable jquery plugins. Basicly what i want to do is this. Take a look at the link below.

[Chart in Table](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B02mJvl83J8sR0h6WHpOSWdBYUU/view?usp=sharing)

I have table with 3 colums and one of the columns has Bar Chart in it. The table is sortable and it has paging to display more rows. With all being sad is there any way to somehow loop trought the chart series and display one for eatch row.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you can use alternate js (chart.js) simple example http://codepedia.info/2015/04/chart-js-simple-bar-chart-example-using-html5-canvas-jquery/

Comment: "*is there any way to somehow loop trought the chart series and display one for eatch row.*"  Well sure. You would just have to loop through each of the chart series and build a chart in each row...  Do you have a more specific question, or a code example? (your google drive link protected)

Answer (score 7):

I wouldn't bother with an external library to create the chart but use CSS instead. This [answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1982966.aspx?Horizontal%20Stacked%20Bar%20Chart%20Help%20) from [Russriguez](http://forums.asp.net/members/Russriguez.aspx) prompted me to look at the CSS you might use. This is a basic example which seems to work and it's on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/tpdkxgve/):

```
<table id="dTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
            <th>Positive/Neutral/Negative</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Votes</th>
            <th>Positive/Neutral/Negative</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>49</td>
            <td>
                <div class="bar-chart-bar">
                    <div class="bar bar1 bar-50"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar2 bar-20"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar3 bar-25"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>German</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>
                <div class="bar-chart-bar">
                    <div class="bar bar1 bar-25"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar2 bar-10"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar3 bar-12"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>French</td>
            <td>28</td>
            <td>
                <div class="bar-chart-bar">
                    <div class="bar bar1 bar-20"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar2 bar-20"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar3 bar-17"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spanish</td>
            <td>16</td>
            <td>
                <div class="bar-chart-bar">
                    <div class="bar bar1 bar-22"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar2 bar-4"></div>
                    <div class="bar bar3 bar-10"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Of course, if your data isn't in that format, it could be interesting as you'll need to format it as you go along. But if it is then you're laughing, as long as you're able to do a wee bit of math to work out the percentages... in fact inline CSS for the stacked bars might make things easier and slim your external CSS.

**EDIT**

I got to thinking about your data and if it's in this format:

```
<table id="dTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Languages</th>
            <th>Positive</th>
            <th>Neutral</th>
            <th>Negative</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>English</td>
            <td>50</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>German</td>
            <td>25</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>12</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>French</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>20</td>
            <td>17</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Spanish</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>10</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then this will work for you:

```
$(function(){
    $("#dTable").dataTable({
        "columns": [
                {
                    "title":"Languages"
                },
                {
                    "title":"Votes",
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return parseInt(row[1], 10) + parseInt(row[2], 10) + parseInt(row[3], 10)
                    }
                },
                {
                    "visible":false
                },
                {
                    "title": "Positive/Neutral/Negative",
                    "sortable":false,
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                        return $("<div></div>", {
                            "class": "bar-chart-bar"
                        }).append(function(){
                            var bars = [];
                            for(var i = 1; i < Object.keys(row).length; i++){
                                bars.push($("<div></div>",{
                                    "class": "bar " + "bar" + i
                                }).css({
                                    "width": row[i] + "%"
                                }))
                            }
                            return bars;
                        }).prop("outerHTML")
                    }
                }
        ]
    });
});
```

With the added benefit of slimming your CSS file ;-)

Working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fqy8mvLh/).

Comment: Thank you for your time. This is the only solution that have found so far  and it is easy one, but this is the last option for me. Because i did't find anything else i'm asking for help here.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with that solution? In my opinion someone just gave you working example with all necessary code..

Answer (score -1):

I derived from previous solution another one. My idea is use [Peity](http://benpickles.github.io/peity/) charts instead CSS code.

Same HTML Code

```
<table id="dTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Languages</th>
        <th>Positive</th>
        <th>Neutral</th>
        <th>Negative</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>English</td>
        <td>50</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>German</td>
        <td>25</td>
        <td>10</td>
        <td>12</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>French</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>17</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Spanish</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>10</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And the Javascript is slighty different,

```
$(function(){
$("#dTable").dataTable({
    "columns": [
            {
                "title":"Languages"
            },
            {
                "title":"Votes",
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                    return parseInt(row[1], 10) + parseInt(row[2], 10) + parseInt(row[3], 10)
                }
            },
            {
                "visible":false
            },
            {
                "title": "Positive/Neutral/Negative",
                "sortable":false,
                "render": function(data, type, row, meta){
                    var sequence = '<span class="donut">'
                                        for(var i = 1; i < row.length; i++){
                     sequence = sequence + parseInt(row[i], 10) + ',';
                   }

                   sequence = sequence + '</span>';                       
                   return sequence
                }
            }
    ]
});
});
$(function() {
    $("span.donut").peity("donut")
})
```

No CSS is used.

a link to [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Iarwain/zvhvpLum/)