# How to display stackbarchart in table foreach row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, charts, highcharts

I have table and 5 column and one of the columns has StackBarChart in it.
Basicly what i want to do is this.[image]
Is there any way to loop chart and display one for each row?
I refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30997562/how-to-display-a-bar-chart-in-datatable) but still didn't work

below is my code

```
<table class="table">
<tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total MD</th>
            <th>Total LR</th>
            <th>Total LB</th>
            <th> Graph</th>
</tr>
@foreach($detail_laka as $laka)
  </tr>
     <td>{{$laka->name}}</td>
     <td>{{$laka->total_md}}</td>
     <td>{{$laka->total_lb}}</td>
     <td>{{$laka->total_lr}}</td>
     <td></td> <!--StackBarChart-->
  </tr>
@endforeach
```

Thanks for the help

Comment: the example use `dataTable` do you want to use it or not?

Comment: Yes, of course, whatever the idea, I will try to achieve the goal. 
is there a link / souce to do that? @AndySong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8zm0c3ok/2/)I think I got mostly working, you may need to tweak a little bit, but the chart should be working.

```css
.bar-chart-bar {
  background-color: #e8e8e8;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

.bar {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar1 {
  background-color: green;
}

.bar2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.bar3 {
  background-color: red;
}

.squareRed {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: red;
}

.squareGreen {
  display: inline-block;

  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: green;
}

.squareYellow {
  display: inline-block;

  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.ib {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```js
function getInt(n) {
  var parsed = parseInt(n);
  return isNaN(parsed) ? 0 : parsed;
}

$(function() {
  $("#dTable").dataTable({
    "columns": [{
        "title": "Name"
      },
      {
        "title": "Total MD"
      },
      {
        "title": "Total LR"
      },
      {
        "title": "Total LB"
      },
      {
        "title": "Graph",
        "sortable": false,
        "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
          return $("<div></div>", {
            "class": "bar-chart-bar"
          }).append(function() {
            var bars = [];
            var total = row.reduce((a, c) => getInt(a) + getInt(c));
            for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
              bars.push($("<div></div>", {
                "class": "bar " + "bar" + i
              }).css({
                "width": (row[i] / total) * 100 + "%"
              }))
            }
            return bars;
          }).prop("outerHTML")
        }
      }
    ]
  });
});
```

```html
<table id="dTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        @foreach($detail_laka as $laka)
        </tr>
        <td>{{$laka->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$laka->total_md}}</td>
        <td>{{$laka->total_lb}}</td>
        <td>{{$laka->total_lr}}</td>
        <td></td> <!--StackBarChart-->
        </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
      <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="5" style="text-align:right">
        <div class="ib">MD: </div>
        <span class="squareRed"></span>
        <div class="ib">LR: </div>
        <span class="squareGreen"></span>
        <div class="ib">LB: </div>
        <span class="squareYellow"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for theanswer. that's very helpful. but I have one more question. how to make that label like the picture above? (red = MD, green = LR, yellow = LB)?

Comment: @chaeusangchen that's just html and css, there are many ways to do that, I have updated my answer, this is just one way to do this.

Comment: thanks, one more question plase. When I bring up 50 rows in the datatable. there is a duplicate **tablehead**. like this image [link](https://ibb.co/Hrwxyxw). how to fix that?

Comment: @chaeusangchen, that's strange, I do not have pc, at the moment, should be able try it in one hour

Comment: I will try to fix it and wait for your answer, sorry to disrupt the time. I'm a beginner using datatable :)

Comment: @chaeusangchen, https://jsfiddle.net/qb3p2ev0/ this is from jsfiddle. it's seems ok.

Comment: oh sorry, my fault. I fixed it. 
I want to add 3 columns, and the stackartart doesn't match MD total, LR total and LB total. like this image [link](https://ibb.co/0VNQDB7).the stackbar still uses MD, LR and LB data. can you help me please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207821/discussion-between-chaeusang-chen-and-andy-song).