# How to display stackbarchart in table foreach row using yajra Datatable?

Tags: jquery, laravel, charts, datatable, yajra-datatable

I have already asked this on this page [stackoverflow.com/questions/60200187](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60200187/how-to-display-stackbarchart-in-table-foreach-row/60200887?noredirect=1#comment106517120_60200887), and try to follow the answer and it's working. But when I add 3 columns, the stackbar is wrong, the stackbar doesn't match with MD total, LR total and LB total. As shown below.
[image]
What I want to do is this
[image]
How to fix that so that the stackbar matches the MD value, LR value and LB value?
Here is my code. Thanks for the help.

```
<table id="dTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody>
@foreach($detail_laka as $laka)
<tr>
    <td>{{$laka->name}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_materialloss}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_accident}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_md}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_lb}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_lr}}</td>
    <td>{{$laka->total_korban}}</td>
    <td></td> <!--StackBarChart-->
</tr>
@endforeach
</tbody>
</table>
```

and javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getInt(n) {
    var parsed = parseInt(n);
    return isNaN(parsed) ? 0 : parsed;
}
$(function() {
   $("#dTable").dataTable({
       "columns": [{
                    "title": "Name"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total Material Loss"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total Kecelakaan"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total MD"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total LR"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total LB"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Total Korban"
                },
                {
                    "title": "Graph",
                    "sortable": false,
                    "render": function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return $("<div></div>", {
                        "class": "bar-chart-bar"
                    }).append(function() {
                        var bars = [];
                        var total = row.reduce((a, c) => getInt(a) + getInt(c));
                        //alert(total);

                        for (var i = 1; i < row.length; i++) {
                        bars.push($("<div></div>", {
                            "class": "bar " + "bar" + i
                            }).css({
                                "width": (row[i] / total) * 100 + "%"
                            }))
                        }
                        return bars;
                    }).prop("outerHTML")
                    }
                }
                ]
      });
  });
</script>
```

style

```
.bar-chart-bar {
     background-color: #e8e8e8;
     display: block;
     position: relative;
     width: 100%;
     height: 20px;
 }

.bar {
     float: left;
     height: 100%;
 }

 .bar1 {
     background-color: green;
 }

 .bar2 {
     background-color: yellow;
  }

  .bar3 {
     background-color: red;
  }
```

Comment: Perhaps you're getting wrong data in $laka? Try `dd($laka);` in your controller method?

Comment: It is not wrong, because the data displayed is correct. The problem is that when I don't display the `Total Material Loss, Total Accident, and Total Korban` columns in the view, the stackbar that is generated is correct. But when I display the column again, the stackbar is wrong. 
Is it wrong in JavaScript? @QumberRizvi